# xamarin forms - webview unsecure connection http

Tags: c#, forms, http, xamarin, webview

Hi i need to connect to **http** without security issues...
this is the link
http://audior.ec/recordmp3js/
when open with **chrome** it shows the problem but not with **firefox**

```
browser.Source = "http://audior.ec/recordmp3js/";
```

this is the log from the website if it work "firefox":
Audio context set up. 
navigator.getUserMedia available. 
Media stream created. 
input sample rate 48000 
Input connected to audio context destination. 
Recorder initialised.

and this one if not working "chrome":

> No live audio input: SecurityError: Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chrome states:

> No live audio input: SecurityError: Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features).

This means you need a secure `https` connection when you want to use your microphone in chrome.

This is a security measure which needs to be implemented at your sever.

You could use a certificate authority to get one (like [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) (it's free)) or use a self signed certificate. Although the latter might not work since it's not always considered to be `secure`

The reason why it works in firefox is because they don't seem to have chosen for such a restriction. This could change in the future.

---

**Web view**

> New Webviews also share the same rendering engine as Chrome for Android, so rendering should be much more consistent between the WebView and Chrome.

See [Android Webview](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview). I am pretty sure Xamarin uses this implementation.

---

**Secure origins**

At the time of writing, these are considered to be secure origins (see link)

> “Secure origins” are origins that match at least one of the following (scheme, host, port) patterns:

```
(https, *, *)
(wss, *, *)
(*, localhost, *)
(*, 127/8, *)
(*, ::1/128, *)
(file, *, —)
(chrome-extension, *, —)
```

Comment: will you 100% right, but my question is not about chrome .. it's about xamarin forms can it make unsecured connection
thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, yes, but you are using a web-view. Underneath is a browser. This (on android) can be chrome. As for more info about web view; it can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview